# Why i have vertical scrollbar in tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a buttons dynamically and add them to table layout panel the problems is that no matter what i do i keep having a vertical scrollbar  even if i have only one row of buttons.
Code :

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
         //   button.Location = new Point(20, 30 * i + 10);
        button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount += 1;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
```

Result : 
[image]

I want to get rid of it the horizontal one is ok

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the height of the horizontal scrollbar to the padding of the control:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  tableLayoutPanel1.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight);

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount += 1;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
```

should get rid of your problem

Comment: because i have autoscroll enabled cause i need it

Comment: so far I know has autoscroll the effect to add both scrollbars without any exceptions. maybe disable autoscroll but enable horizontalscroll?

Comment: yes but if i disable autoscroll and enable horizontalscroll the horizontal scroll it not working (scrolling) anymore

Answer (score 0):

I work around the problem by padding my TableLayoutPanel control to account for the VeritcalScrollBarWidth.

This is VB.net but you get the point:

```
    'Prevent Constant Horizontal Scrollbar by padding for the VerticalBar
    MyTableLayoutPanel.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 0)
```